# Django/Python: Calling a model/class function with an argument from Template

Tags: python, django, class, templates, arguments

In Django 2.0, I'm trying to call a method from a class, from a template.

Call from template

```
{% activity.liked_by(user) %}
```

Method from class

```
class Activity(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def liked_by(self, user):
        return Like.objects.filter(activity_id=self.id, user_id=user.id)
```

I know this isn't possible, but what would be the best alternative? There's no way I can execute the query without passing user as an argument.

Thanks!

Comment: Call `result = test.method(user)` in the view that renders the template and add the result to the template context.

Comment: @Blurp Thanks, but then I'm missing the class where I'm calling it from (ie. self).

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @Blurp I'm calling the query from a class in models.py, self.id is from the class I'm calling it from. So if I were to call it from the view, then I'm missing an argument for the query.

Comment: The data you pass to the templates should be handled by views, not models. So your method should be a view, to which you pass the parameters you need. Or a template tag as @Stuart Dines answer. Also you didn't post the model class to which you refer in the comments.

Comment: @SJ19 If you have an instance of a class, properly initialized, it doesn't matter where you call its methods from. You probably need to show more of your code so it's clear what's going on.

Comment: @guillermochamorro Edited my post, views are tied to urls, I literally just need to find one integer for a user (it's for a button).

Comment: @Blurp Edited my post, I simply need to find an integer for a user (for which I need to use the query).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either provide the query in the context passed to the template or use a [custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-tags). Lets assume the file that is created is called `my_template_tags.py` (note that this file must me in the correct directory structure).

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def get_method(test, user):
    return Test.objects.filter(test_id=test.id, user_id=user.id)
```

And then in the template:

```
{% load my_template_tags %}
{% get_method test user %}
```

Comment: I'm confused, so you don't add this into models.py?

Comment: I'm getting this error: TemplateSyntaxError at /todo/global_activities.html
'my_template_tags' is not a registered tag library. Must be one of:

Comment: No you wont need to add it into `models.py`. When you create `my_template_tags.py` it must be within an installed app under a folder named `templatetags` with an `__init__.py` in it. For the structure please refer to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#code-layout

Comment: This may be a silly question, but how do I add an additional app? lol

Comment: Not at all; the app is the folder that contains the `models.py` file that the `Activity` class is in. For instance if your `models.py` file is in a folder names `activities` create a new folder within `activities` named `templatetags`. Withing `templatetags` create a file named `__init__.py` which can be empty. Also within `templatetags` create a file named `my_template_tags.py` and that is where the template tag goes. You will need to restart your server after this.

Comment: Alright I'm getting this error: TemplateSyntaxError at /todo/global_activities.html 'my_template_tags' is not a registered tag library. Must be one of:

Comment: Nevermind! I initially made a new app called templatetags, rather than just doing what you described (adding a new folder to my app).

Comment: Now my final question would be, how can I turn {% get_method test user %} into an if statement?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161775/discussion-between-sj19-and-stuart-dines).

Comment: You can wrap it in an `if` e.g. `{% if user and test %}{% get_method test user %}{% endif %}`

Comment: @SJ19 you don't need to create a new app, also you lose the functionality of templatetags module. You got the error because you need to load your templatetags in your templates `{% load my_template_tag %}`